# NSLocalizedStringFromTable change default language at runtime

Tags: ios

I'm using this line to change the default language

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"it"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate
```

and using this line to get the value

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"text", @"PA", nil);
```

Only issue is that I need to restart the app for the changes to be applied.

When i call NSLocalizedStringFromTable it always return from the language before the change

Is it possible to let the user have the option to change the local language without exiting the app?

Here is a sample project i created that demonstrate the issue
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13431688/LocalizationTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible. What you could do is to have in your `Localizable.strings` file key-value pairs like

```
"en.error.general" = "An error occured.";
"fr.error.general" = "...";
```

then define a macro like:

```
#define LocalizedString(key, language) [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", language, key] value:key table:nil]
```

and call it by `LocalizedString(@"error.general", @"en");`